# Apache Beam Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing a dataflow jobs. I have joined two datasets using CoGroupByKey. I want to implement lookup on another dataset. 
I have a dictionary generated on the join of two datasets. Now I want to lookup on a key of this dictionary in some other dataset and want to fetch some other key value pairs to append in this dataset.

It would be similar to writing a lookup query in SQL.
Primary key: SearchId
Want to do lookup on: UserId.
1 SearchId can have multiple UserIds and not all UserIds data is present in the dataset. How to do this efficiently in Apache Beam using python ?

Adding the code snippet and sample data format.

```
def dict_tuple1(dict_line):
    """Convert PCollection dict to a tuple """
    row = {}
    row[dict_line.get('UserID')] = dict_line
    return (dict_line.get('UserID'), dict_line)


def tuple_to_string1(tuple):
    (key,value) = tuple
    list = sorted(value['join_joined_dicts']) + sorted(value['UserDict'])
    print(list)
    print(len(list))
    dictionary = {}
    for i in xrange(len(list)):
        try:
            dictionary.update(list[i])
        except IndexError:
            return(dictionary)
    return(dictionary) 

def timestamp_conv(dictionary):
    from datetime import datetime
    date_converted = datetime.strptime(dictionary['SearchDate'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    dictionary['SearchDate'] = date_converted
    return(dictionary)





def run(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input', default=r'D:\dummy_codes\source\search_info.txt')
    parser.add_argument('--output', default=r'D:\dummy_codes\source\search')

    # parser.add_argument('--project', default='PROJECT_ID')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DirectRunner'
    #pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project = 'PROJECT_ID'
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)


    source_data = (p | 'readSearchInfo' >> beam.io.Read(CsvFileSource(r'D:\dummy_codes\source\SearchInfo_user.tsv', delimiter='\t', header=True, dictionary_output=True))
                     | beam.Map(timestamp_conv)
                    )


    source_data2 = (p | 'readUserInfo' >> beam.io.Read(CsvFileSource(r'D:\dummy_codes\source\user_data.tsv', delimiter='\t', header=True, dictionary_output=True)))


    UserDict = (source_data2 | 'keyUserDict' >>  beam.Map(dict_tuple1))

    join_joined_dicts = (source_data | 'join_dicts' >>  beam.Map(dict_tuple1))

    joined_dicts_1 = (
        {'join_joined_dicts': join_joined_dicts ,'UserDict': UserDict}
        | 'Cogroup1' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
        | beam.Map(tuple_to_string1) 
    )
```

with headers for both file:
File 1

```
SearchID    SearchDate  IPID    UserID  IsUserLoggedOn  SearchQuery LocationID  CategoryID  SearchParams
```

File2

```
UserID  first_name  last_name   company_name    zip phone1  phone2  email
```

We want to implement file1 left outer join file2. We can have multiple users for 1 searchId. We want to get all the users in the output rather than only 1 being picked up by above code.

Comment: What is your current solution? Please update your question with some code snippets. Also: why don't you just use CoGroupByKey for a second time?

Comment: As suggested by @MarcinZablocki, we will need some information about what you have already achieved and a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) over which we can work.

Comment: Updated with code snippet and data headers.